# Configuring Homestead to work for Windows Users

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

**EDIT: See updated section below, where I modified the Code according to given solution suggestions**

I am using vagrant with homestead on my win7 machine. And I want to install some gulp packages for example gulp-uncss, which does not work because I get the error added below.

After some research and discussions in the #npm IRC channel I was hinted to this problem here:

https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#running-a-vagrant-box-on-windows-fails-due-to-path-length-issues

According to this entry, windows users still have a problem when using vagrant, because the shared folder between host and guest machine has the max-character limitation of 260 characters, which has always been a major issue with windows development.

A solution seems to be to change the vagrant file and the provisions along with it.

Here is the initial error:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo$ gulp uncss
[10:51:07~/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/gulpfile.js
[10:51:07] Starting 'uncss'...

/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:43
        fn = function () { throw arg; };
                                 ^
TypeError: Bad argument
    at TypeError (native)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1136:26)
    at /home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/lib/spawn.js:82:38
    at init (/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/node_modules/when/lib/makePro
    at new Promise (/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:27:53)
    at Function.promise (/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/node_modules/when/when.js:97:10)
    at startPhantom (/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/lib/spawn.js:58:25)
    at tryCatchReject (/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:845:30)
    at runContinuation1 (/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:804:4)
    at Fulfilled.when (/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:592:4)
    at Pending.run (/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:483:13)
    at Scheduler._drain (/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/node_modules/when/lib/Scheduler.js:62:19)
    at Scheduler.drain (/home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress/wp-content/themes/expimo/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/node_modules/when/lib/Scheduler.js:27:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

As I have understood from the entry, is that I have to modify my Vagrantfile and maybe even add some provisions?

This is my the current default Vagrantfile added through homestead:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

homesteadYamlPath = File.expand_path("~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml")
afterScriptPath = File.expand_path("~/.homestead/after.sh")
aliasesPath = File.expand_path("~/.homestead/aliases")

require_relative 'scripts/homestead.rb'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
end
```

And apparently I have to insert the modifications stated here:
https://github.com/renobit/vagrant-node-env/commit/bdf15f2f301e2b1660b839875e34f172ea8be227

inside this Vagrantfile, so that homestead works properly windows.

Since I just started using vagrant, my knowledge is very limited, therefore I would welcome any help I can get on this topic. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

**UPDATE to David Myers suggestion:**

I modified my Vagrantfile according to David Myers suggestion below to no avail:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end


        # this should be inserted right before the "Homestead.configure()" line
        config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v, override|
            if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
                override.vm.synced_folder "./Code", "/home/vagrant/Code", disabled: true

                v.customize ["sharedfolder", "add", :id, "--name", "Code", "--hostpath", (("//?/" + File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/Code").gsub("/","\\"))]

                override.vm.provision :shell, inline: "mkdir -p /home/vagrant/Code"
                override.vm.provision :shell, inline: "mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` Code /home/vagrant/Code", run: "always"
            else
                override.vm.synced_folder "./Code", "/home/vagrant/Code"
            end

            v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/Code", "1"]
        end
        # this should be inserted right before the "Homestead.configure()" line



    Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
end
```

And I also commented out the three lines you pointed out in my Homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# folders:
#    - map: ~/Code
#      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: expimo.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Wordpress
    - map: laravel.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Unfortunately then I get the Error Message:

**No input file specified**, because it seems the URIs are not directed to the right folder.

If I then just uncomment the three lines again in my homestead.yaml file, and keep the modified Vagrantfile, I get the same error, when I am trying to install gulp-uncss through "npm install gulp-uncss --save-dev".

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the one who implemented that fix you mentioned. :)

I personally haven't run into this issue with Homestead yet, but I think I know what you need to do. First, you will need to comment out these lines in the `Homestead.yaml` file:

```
folders
- map: ~/Code
  to:  /home/vagrant/Code
```

Next, you'll need to add this configuration to your `Vagrantfile`:

```rb
# this should be inserted right before the "Homestead.configure()" line
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v, override|
    if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
        override.vm.synced_folder "./Code", "/home/vagrant/Code", disabled: true

        v.customize ["sharedfolder", "add", :id, "--name", "Code", "--hostpath", (("//?/" + File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/Code").gsub("/","\\"))]

        override.vm.provision :shell, inline: "mkdir -p /home/vagrant/Code"
        override.vm.provision :shell, inline: "mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` Code /home/vagrant/Code", run: "always"
    else
        override.vm.synced_folder "./Code", "/home/vagrant/Code"
    end

    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/Code", "1"]
end
# this should be inserted right before the "Homestead.configure()" line
```

Note the comments in the previous block; you need to make sure it is inserted before the Homestead configuration is run.

NOTE: This script assumes you are sharing a directory called "Code" that is located in the same directory as this Vagrantfile.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your effort. Unfortunatley the solution does seem not to be that simple, since it still does not work. I updated my entry above to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: Would you mind telling me where the shared directory is located on your machine?

Comment: It is just in C:/Users/Georg/Code   

Proof: http://imgur.com/IYLqPEp,lGE9f4Z,d7ak6vQ

Comment: Did you happen to change the code I posted to reflect that? The code above looks for a "Code" directory in the same directory that you are calling "vagrant up" from. If it is in a different directory, you may need to change the code above to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

I put up a full guide/walkthrough for Homestead on Windows that addresses all these issues (and others, like caching problems with winnfsd/etc) and solutions for Laravel 5 & Lumen. I will be keeping this Gist up-to-date (and continually improve it's readability). You can find the Gist here: https://gist.github.com/prograhammer/9493ee04f30dd74e121b

In that Gist, I had to add a few steps to David Myers solution:

Update `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.7.2\plugins\providers\virtualbox\driver\version_4_3.rb` somewhere near lines 495-510, replace the line `folder[:hostpath]` with `'\\\\?\\' + folder[:hostpath].gsub(/[\/\\]/,'\\')]`

Update `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.7.2\lib\vagrant\util\platform.rb` and comment out a big part of this section:

```
# This expands the path and ensures proper casing of each part
# of the path.

def fs_real_path(path, **opts)

  #path = Pathname.new(File.expand_path(path))
  #
  # if path.exist? && !fs_case_sensitive?
  #  # Build up all the parts of the path
  #  original = []
  #  while !path.root?
  #    original.unshift(path.basename.to_s)
  #    path = path.parent
  #  end
  #
  #  # Traverse each part and join it into the resulting path
  #  original.each do |single|
  #    Dir.entries(path).each do |entry|
  #     if entry.downcase == single.encode('filesystem').downcase
  #       path = path.join(entry)
  #     end
  #    end
  #  end
  #end
  #
  # if windows?
  #  # Fix the drive letter to be uppercase.
  #  path = path.to_s
  #  if path[1] == ":"
  #    path[0] = path[0].upcase
  #  end
  #
  #  path = Pathname.new(path)
  #end

  path
end
```

Now vagrant up.